# Why auto doesn't work if implementation is in a separate file?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, auto

Consider the following example:

```
class MyClass
{
    const int _id;
public:
    MyClass(auto id) : _id(id) {} 
};

int main()
{
    MyClass(3);

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine.

Also

```
class MyClass
{
    const int _id;
public:
    MyClass(auto id);
};

MyClass::MyClass(auto id) : _id(id)
{
}

int main()
{
    MyClass(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Works fine.

However,

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class MyClass
{
    const int _id;
public:
    MyClass(auto id);
};

#endif
```

and

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(auto id) : _id(id)
{
}
```

and

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
    MyClass(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives this linker error:

```
/tmp/ccJQ1HNz.o: In function `main':
deduce.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `MyClass::MyClass<int>(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So it has to do something with templates .. But where do they come in?

Comment: Because templates are statically linked and must go to the header ;)

Comment: @101010 : I know that, but does auto generates some templates for me?

Comment: Somewhat shady question as what you are doing is not standard yet, but it's the same mechanism. It's part of the concepts TS afaik, so I hope we get that by 2020.

Comment: @otisonoza Yes, how else could it be?

Comment: `MyClass(auto id);` declares a template function. This isn't standard but it is in the Concepts TS. It gets transformed into `template<typename T> MyClass(T id);`